# Form input VIRTUAL keyCode capture. How?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

```js
// Bind keydown event to all input type=text in form.
$("form input[type=text]").keydown(function (e) {

// Reference to keyCodes...
var key = e.which || e.keyCode;

// ONLY Allow Numbers, Backspace & Tab
if((key >= 48 && key <=57) || (key >= 96 && key <=105) || (key >= 8 && key <=9)) {

    // Allow
    return true;

    } else {

    // Deny
    return false;
    }            

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="">

<label for="text1">Text Box:</label>
<input id="text1" type="text" placeholder="0">

</form>
```

I have the following code that binds a keyDown event on all inputs of type text in a form. This works great.

What it's not happening is, the 
[Optionally fixed virtual key codes](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-dom/2010JulSep/att-0182/keyCode-spec.html) **are not being trapped**!

Why is this happening when every keyCode that isn't true should not trigger?

```
// Bind keydown event to all input type=text in form.
$("form input[type=text]").keydown(function (e) {

// Reference to keyCodes...
var key = e.which || e.keyCode;

// ONLY Allow Numbers, Backspace & Tab
if((key >= 48 && key <=57) || (key >= 96 && key <=105) || (key >= 8 && key <=9)) {

    // Allow
    return true;

    } else {

    // Deny
    return false;
    }            

});
```

Comment: Which key is getting triggered?

Comment: Anything Shift + Whatever. For instance, Shift + [0 - 9]. These inputs are integer database fields and anything else entered by a user would prevent the record from being inserted due to MySQL column datatype compatibility issues.

Comment: [UX: Text Field Validation vs Prevention](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/56290/text-field-validation-vs-prevention)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about trying a different approach. Here's a simple keyup event handler that uses regex to remove any non-numeric characters right after they're typed.

```js
$("input[type=text]").on("keyup", function() {
var new_val = $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
$(this).val(new_val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, after about an hour, **this worked**.

Below, you may find a working version catering to shift + key for now. I'll be making it more complete soon.

Apple iPad keyboard keys...

I had to create a keyPress event handler to capture and suppress keys on the iPad that don't seem to be handled by the keyDown event or are ambiguous???!

```js
// Bind keydown event to all input type=text in form.
$("form input[type=text]").keydown(function (e) {

// Reference to keyCodes...
var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
// Reference to shiftKey...
var shift_key = e.shiftKey;
// Reference to ctrlKey...
var ctrl_key = e.ctrlKey;
// Reference to altKey...
var alt_key = e.altKey;


// When user presses the shiftKey...
if(e.shiftKey) {

//...supress its click and whatever key follows after it.
console.log(e.shiftKey + ' and ' + key + ' supressed.');

// Deny
return false;

// ONLY Allow Numbers, Backspace & Tab
} else if ( (key >= 48 && key <=57) || (key >= 96 && key <=105) || (key >= 8 && key <=9) ) {

// Allow
return true;

} else {

// Deny every other key and/or shift + key combination NOT explicitly declared.
return false;
}

});


// KeyPresss to handle remaining iPAD keyboard keys!
// These keys don't seem to be handled by the keyDown event or are ambiguous???!
// Bind keypress event to all input type=text in form.
$("form input[type=text]").keypress(function (e) {

// Reference to keyCodes...
var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
// Reference to shiftKey...
var shift_key = e.shiftKey;
// Reference to ctrlKey...
var ctrl_key = e.ctrlKey;
// Reference to altKey...
var alt_key = e.altKey;

switch (key) {

// Character -> ^
case 94:
return false;

// Character -> #
case 35:
return false;

// Character -> $
case 36:
return false;

// Character -> @
case 64:
return false;

// Character -> &
case 38:
return false;

// Character -> *
case 42:
return false;

// Character -> (
case 40:
return false;

// Character -> )
case 41:
return false;

// Character -> %
case 37:
return false;

// Character -> !
case 33:
return false;

}


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="">

<label for="text1">Text Box:</label>
<input id="text1" type="text" placeholder="0">

</form>
```